# Como eu faço para meu jQuery percorrer essa tabela de forma correta?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu criei um script para percorrer a tabela e me retornar um console.log do conteúdo nela, mas nas primeiras linhas não pega o nome do Curso, apenas os preços.

Vi que na TD da tabela onde diz DIREITO, tem um rowspan=2 no css.
Mas não sei que condição devo usar para meu script ler de forma correta.

Link da tabela que quero percorrer com jQuery:

http://www.ciesa.br/details-menu/107-indicadores-de-qualidade-2.html

Meu código está da seguinte forma:

```
var c = [];
            jQuery('table tbody tr:gt(4)').each(function(ii, tr){
                if($(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text().indexOf("R$")>-1){
                    var price = {
                        course_name: $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                        price: $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
                        turn: 'Matutino'
                    };
                    c.push(price);

                    var price = {
                        course_name: $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                        price: $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
                        turn: 'Vespertino'
                    };
                    c.push(price);

                    var price = {
                        course_name: $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                        price: $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
                        turn: 'Noturno'
                    };
                    c.push(price);

                    }
            }); console.log(c);
```

Comment: Pegar o nome do curso é até fácil, o problema é saber que preço é de quê. Por exemplo, como vai saber que Direito é 1.100 no matutino e vespertino e 1.200 no noturno se estão em linhas diferentes e em colunas diferentes?

Comment: Pois então, o que ta rolando é isso. Só não sei como criar um if específico pra essa linha no começo que tá fora

Comment: Pois eh. Tem que fazer um if cabuloso pra achar os respectivos valores. Vou ver se consigo aqui.

Comment: To tentando também, mas ainda sem sucesso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz desta forma onde eu separo variáveis para cada turno, verificando se a coluna possui `rowspan` para poder pegar o valor correspondente do turno. Para pegar o nome do curso, você pode colocar no `if` um `.prev()`.

```
var c = [];
jQuery('table tbody tr:gt(4)').each(function(ii, tr){

   if($(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text().indexOf("R$") > -1){

      var curso = $(tr).prev().find('td:eq(0)').text();
      var colspan0 = $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').attr('colspan');
      var colspan1 = $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').attr('colspan');

      if(colspan0 == 2){
         var price_m = price_v = $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text();
         var price_n = $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text();
      }else if(colspan1 == 2){
         var price_m = $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text();
         var price_v = price_n = $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text();
      }else{
         var price_m = price_v = price_n = $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text();
      }

   }else if($(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text().indexOf("R$") > -1){
      var curso = $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text();
      var price_m = price_v = price_n = $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text();
   }

   // só vai fazer o .push se o nome do curso for true
   if(curso){

      var price = {
         course_name: curso,
         price: price_m,
         turn: 'Matutino'
      };
      c.push(price);

      var price = {
         course_name: curso,
         price: price_v,
         turn: 'Vespertino'
      };
      c.push(price);

      var price = {
         course_name: curso,
         price: price_n,
         turn: 'Noturno'
      };
      c.push(price);
   }

}); console.log(c);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1usrkjw0/)**

Comment: Cara, era exatamente isso! Eu estava horas tentando montar algo assim. Mas como sou bem iniciante ainda eu me quebro pra montar códigos e pesquisar bastante pra fazer uma estrutura funcional. Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

O texto que pretendes está numa linha que não estás a percorrer :/
com a instrução `table tbody tr:gt(4)` estás a começar pela linha que não tem nada na primeira coluna devido ao colspan, se começares pela `table tbody tr:gt(3)`
conseguirás apanhar o "Direito" mas terás de fazer um if especifico para esse caso pois da forma que está não entra e nao faz push no array.

Comment: Pois então, esse if específico que não sei exatamente como fazer, como sou iniciante eu peco nisso. Essa foi a forma que eu consegui buscar 90% da tabela, mas esse começo ta me quebrando.